# Getaddrinfo() returning wildcard addresses despite AI_PASSIVE not being set

Tags: c, dns

From the man page for getaddrinfo()...

> If the AI_PASSIVE flag is not set in hints.ai_flags, then the
>          returned socket addresses will be suitable for use with connect(2),
>          sendto(2), or sendmsg(2).

but I'm getting `0.0.0.0` returned for some websites. Shouldn't I not be getting wildcard addresses?

```
void checkAddresses(char * addrName)
{
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo * infoptr = 0;
    struct addrinfo * node = 0;
    int gai_return = 0;
    int socket_fd = 0;
    int gni_return = 0;
    char host_buffer[255] = { 0 };
    struct sockaddr_in * h = 0;

    memset(host_buffer, 0, sizeof(host_buffer));

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints.ai_flags = 0;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;
    hints.ai_canonname = NULL;
    hints.ai_addr = NULL;
    hints.ai_next = NULL;

    gai_return = getaddrinfo(addrName, 0, &hints, &infoptr);
    if(gai_return != 0)
    {
        perror("Getaddrinfo() failure");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (node = infoptr; node != NULL; node = node->ai_next)
    {
        h = (struct sockaddr_in *) node->ai_addr;
        strcpy(host_buffer, inet_ntoa(h->sin_addr));
        puts(host_buffer);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(infoptr);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified `AF_UNSPEC`, which means unspecified address family. **Now** this means that you will get both `AF_INET` and `AF_INET6` . If all you want is `AF_INET` then please say so.

Notice that especially if you're looking up `localhost`, the IPv6 address `::1` will have the binary representation

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01
```

Now if you reinterpret the first 4 bytes as an IPv4 address (as will happen if you cast the pointer to `struct sockaddr_in *`)...

---

With `AF_UNSPEC` you must check the `node->ai_family`; it would be `AF_INET` for IPv4 sockets and `AF_INET6` for IPv6 - and possibly something else for something else.

Notice however that most of the time you wouldn't be inspecting the addresses at all - there is no need. Instead you'd just pass the uncast `struct sockaddr *ai_addr` to `sendto` (for UDP sockets) as such.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I didn't realize `sockaddr_in` and `inet_ntoa` are IPv4 specific. I'll have to figure out how to differentiate them when looping or just loop twice (also, I made sure to not use `AF_UNSPEC` and instead specified IPv4 and IPv5`. Thank you.